# How to disable pagespeed in the Bitnami stack?

Tags: apache, bitnami, mod-pagespeed

The Bitnami stack has pagespeed enabled by default. While in development it won't be used. How can I disable pagespeed in the bitnami stack?

Comment: I edited the title to be a proper question in a single sentence. I applied the same improvement to the body of your question. *Disable* is a better word than *stop*. I removed the reference to your answer from the question. I changed the correct tag for pagespeed according to the tag excerpt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

change `ModPagespeed on` to `ModPagespeed off` in `lampstack-x.x.x/apache2/conf/pagespeed.conf` then restart your server

Answer (score 7):

How to disable PageSpeed?

To disable PageSpeed, follow these steps:

```
Comment out the following lines in the installdir/apache2/conf/httpd.conf file:

 Include conf/pagespeed.conf
 Include conf/pagespeed_libraries.conf
```

ref: https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/components/pagespeed/

Comment: installdir = ~/stack/apache2/conf

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on a ligthsail box with WordPress with the following commands.

```
sudo vim /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Search the file by typing /pagespeed

And press I to insert and then comment out these two lines.

```
#Include conf/pagespeed.conf
#Include conf/pagespeed_libraries.conf
```

Restart apache

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```